# Converter entrada em data com oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, conversão-de-tipo

Estou com problemas para retornar os resultados da query a seguir, aonde eu coloco a variavel &mes, se eu coloca-se '01-sep-2017' traria os resultados que preciso, porém na caixa de dialogo queria que o usuario digita-se com os padrões utilizados para data, sendo o correto '01/09/2017', porém ao entrar com essa data é apresentado o erro ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

```
Select a.pro_st_alternativo,
   a.pro_st_descricao,
   mgadm.adm_pck_estoque.F_SALDO_QTDE(20,21,a.pro_pad_in_codigo,a.pro_in_codigo,1,null,null,to_char(to_date(&mes), 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'AN')Saldo_mes,

   a.uni_st_unidade,
   a.pro_bo_controlalotes,
   a.pro_st_cestoque,
   a.pro_st_defitem,
   A.PRO_CH_DEFFISCALITEM,
   A.PRO_ST_ORIGEM

From mgadm.est_produtos a
Where A.PRO_PAD_IN_CODIGO = 4;
```

Comment: Se a data já está sendo recebida no parâmetro no formato que você quer é só utilizar dessa forma para convertê-la para `date`: `to_date(&mes, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma função no PL/SQL chamada `to_date`. Ela é responsável por realizar esta conversão, ficando assim:

```
to_date(&mes, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Alguns exemplo de mascaras:

```
TO_DATE('2003/07/09', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
retorna: July 9, 2003

TO_DATE('070903', 'MMDDYY')
Retorna: July 9, 2003

TO_DATE('20020315', 'yyyymmdd')
Retorna: Mar 15, 2002
```

Você pode achar a lista completa de mascaras [aqui](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php).

Comment: Obrigado Luiz, para ficar do jeito que eu queria eu precisei adicionar '&mes' na variavel, asism dessa mesma forma que eu coloquei ai em cima o usuário só precisa digitar a data sem colocar '01/01/2017'

Comment: Otimo :) Que bom que funcionou